# Implement password recovery best practice

Tags: passwords, password-recovery, forgot-password

I want to to implement password recovery in my web application.

I'd like to avoid using secret questions.

I could just send the password by e-mail but I think it would be risky.

Maybe I could generate a new temporary random password and send it by e-mail but I think it is as risky as the above point.

Can I send a url by e-mail for example http://example.com/token=xxxx
where xxxx is a random token associated with the user. So when the user navigates to that url he/she can reset the password.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910856/effective-techniques-for-password-retrieval-in-modern-web-applications

Comment: ps. When the user arrives on the password reset page with the right token, keep using that token (or another temporary token) to update the right record on form submit with the new password. If you use something like record-id instead (after having found the right record) people can reset one another's password using that, instead of a token.. just something I found out while writing one of these myself :-)

Comment: Check similar question on IT Security ( StackExchange ) 

http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1918/can-anyone-provide-references-for-implementing-web-application-self-password-res

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First off, do **not** store a plain-text copy of the user's password, or even an encrypted version. You want to only ever keep a **hashed** copy of the user's password.

As for recover solutions, I find that the recovery link to change the user's password is the best solution in my experience. It will probably be a bit more convenient for the user, while being largely the same from a security point of view as sending a new random password to be changed after next login. I'd still recommend having the recovery url expire after a reasonable short period of time, as well as only being usable a single time.

Comment: I am about to try to implement this for the first time. I only keep hashed passwords as you say, could you elaborate a little bit about the recovery link method. I have seen it done with something like so: `http://site.com/reset-pass?e='+user.email+'&p='+user.pass` where the password field is the hash, is this secure? If someone gets a hold of the hashes for your database, does this mean they can reset everyone's password? How would you implement links that expire?

Comment: @CoryGross There's various ways you could go about this, but you definitely don't want the link to in any way expose the email or pass/hash. A fairly simple option would be an additional table in your database, with a User ID column (unique), the request data column, and a *randomly generated* value (128 bits would a safe value). The randomly generated value would be embedded in the link in the email. The reset-pass page would ensure the number it gets is in the database & the date is within X days. At that point, you could then ask for a new password for the user. Prune periodically.

Comment: What would a "short period of time" be? Hours? Days? A week?

Comment: @Joe Minutes/hours might not be practical (both due to email providers occasionally being *very* slow at delivery, and maybe circumstances for the user). There's likely a *sweet spot* somewhere between a day and a week. If you have access to the data, you could graph how long it takes your users to actually use the recovery link, and then adjust it based on that data to try to minimize the annoyance to users, while preserving their security (you might lean more one way or the other). Sadly I haven't heard of any studies of this sort being done, although it'd likely have informative results.

Comment: It should be mentioned here, that you should use a cryptographic hash function for hashing. Something like SHA-2. "Hashing" in computer science is a little bit generic and when you don't use a cryptographic hash function, you end up with security holes as wide as the rocky mountains.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: SHA-2, even with a salt, really is not adequate for secure password. To be technical, you should be using a *key derivation function*, rather than a generic cryptographic hash function, like PBKDF2, bcrypt, and scrypt. Regular cryptographic hash functions are simply too fast.

Comment: I wonder if we (the devs) should offer users to store a public key so they can receive encrypted emails. This would lower the risk for a recovery link being sniffed. (I guess 0.01% of all users would use it but I'm just wondering how to increase security)

Answer (score 85):

When I was in the Air Force the security rule we had was: When setting or resetting passwords, do not send the user id and the password in the same email. That way, if someone is intercepting emails snooping for passwords, he has to successfully intercept BOTH emails, and be able to connect them, to breach security.

I've seen a lot of sites that use the "go to this URL to reset your password". Maybe I'm missing something -- I don't claim to be a security expert -- but I don't see how that is any more secure than just inventing a new, temporary password and sending it. If a hacker intercepts the email, why can't he go to that link and see the new password as well as the legitimate user could? It looks to me like extra hassle for the user with no security gain.

By the way, congratulations on NOT using security questions. The logic of this device escapes me. Since the dawn of computer security we have been telling people, "DON'T make a password that is information about yourself that a hacker could discover or guess, like the name of your high school, or your favorite color. A hacker might be able to look up the name of your high school, or even if they don't know you or know anything about you, if you still live near where you went to school they might get it by tryinging local schools until they hit it. There are a small number of likely favorite colors so a hacker could guess that. Etc. Instead, a password should be a meaningless combination of letters, digits, and punctuation." But now we also tell them, "But! If you have a difficult time remembering that meaningless combination of letters, digits, and punctuation, no problem! Take some information about yourself that you can easily remember -- like the name of your high school, or your favorite color -- and you can use that as the answer to a 'security question', that is, as an alternative password."

Indeed, security questions make it even easier for the hacker than if you just chose a bad password to begin with. At least if you just used a piece of personal information for your password, a hacker wouldn't necessarily know what piece of personal information you used. Did you use the name of your dog? Your birth date? Your favorite ice cream flavor? He'd have to try all of them. But with security questions, we tell the hacker exactly what piece of personal information you used as a password!

Instead of using security questions, why don't we just say, "In case you forget your password, it is displayed on the bottom of the screen. If you're trying to hack in to someone else's account, you are absolutely forbidden from scrolling down." It would be only slightly less secure.

Lest you wonder, when sites ask me for the city where I was born or the manufacturer of my first car, I do not give an actual answer tot he question. I give a meaningless password.

</rant>

Comment: +1 For most enjoyable rant about why security questions are bad.

Comment: I always choose obscure answers for those awful "security" questions. I had an awkward moment with my wireless provider recovering my password over the phone. They asked me one of the security questions I had set up: "What is your favorite food?", to which I replied, "Myself"... "Um, OK Mr. Murch thank you very much."

Comment: @Wesley: It could have been worse. You could have said, "help desk people". Not a bad idea though. A ridiculous answer would be easy to remember, but less likely for someone to guess. As long as you don't choose an obvious ridiculous answer. Like, Q: "Where did you go to school?" A: "Hard knocks".

Comment: If you send a new password for them to access the site, it could be intercepted down the road, and if the user has yet to change their password since the incident, that password is still valid. The usage of a server-side generated token allows you, the site owner, to have better control over when they are able to use that entry point, by means of an expiry.

Comment: "Go to this URL to reset your password." Once you are there, please provide your username, which was *NOT* included in the email, and the token will expire within an hour. This is more secure than a temporary password, since it doesn't lock you out of your account if you didn't make the request. The hacker must know both your username and email address and have access to the latter for the time-frame in which the token is valid. Of course, this assumes the site is not using your email address as your username ...

Comment: So you've went on a rant about security questions but did not propose a better solution. Is there another step of authentication after a password that can be used securely?

Comment: The question was about password recovery or reset, and I made my suggestion: Send the password in an email that does NOT include the user id. If you want to ask about security methods that do not include passwords, that's another question, and we shouldn't clutter up this thread with a different topic.

Comment: Setting a temporary password will lock out the original user. That's why they are not a good idea and why they rarely used.

Comment: @NickG Temporary passwords may be a bad idea -- after seeing Aejay's and Duncan's comments I agree -- but I don't think they are "rarely used". I see them a lot.

Comment: How can two mails for reset ever be more secure than one mail plus a security question when the security question is only used for password recovery and has a failed attempt counter? According to your answer the best option would be to split the auto-generated password across multiple emails because you say the more emails the better security gets.

Comment: @user764754 See my rant about security questions. A determined hacker could do research or make educated guesses and find the answers to your security questions. It doesn't matter how often a security question is used. If, say, it's the name of your high school, whether you type this in once a year or twice a day makes no difference to how easy it is for a hacker to find or guess. Yes, I'd suppose that splitting a new password across 10 emails would make it harder to intercept, but then the user would have to assemble it. ...

Comment: ... You have to balance burden to the legitimate user with keeping out intruders. This is, by the way, analogous to a method actually used by spies: Get 3 couriers. Give courier #1 words 1, 4, 7, 10, etc. Give courier #2 words 2, 5, 8, 11, etc. Give courier #3 words 3, 6, 9, 12, etc. Then if an enemy captures one courier, they only have 1/3 of the message and will have a harder time getting information from it. Less cloak-and-dagger: I once read the advice that when you throw away an old credit card or something else with an account number on it, you should cut it in pieces, and ...

Comment: ... dispose of different pieces in different garbage cans. Then a thief who tries searching your garbage to get account numbers will only get part of the account number.

Comment: I use 30 characters long randomly generated passcode for my security questions

Comment: @kun I don't go that far -- I usually use nonsense words that I invent. Your method is more secure than mine, though more trouble to manage. I wouldn't bother for, say, an account on a forum like this one. If someone accesses my account, they can make posts in my name and make me look foolish or rude, but I do that myself often enough anyway. For a retirement account, different story.

Comment: @Jay actually, the security questions are for my Apple ID. Lots of my personal information are stored on iCloud in my case. I rely on keychain in my mac to store these in the format of secure notes.

Comment: I'm suddenly reminded of the person who said that he was careful to use a meaningless jumble of letters for his cell phone password. And because that's hard to remember, he wrote it on a sticker and stuck it to the cell phone.

Answer (score 20):

Hard to say what you **should** do, as pretty much any solution to this problem will weaken security. Unless maybe you want to investigate sending an SMS, callback verification, one-time password generators, or other such schemes that take password recovery to a different medium.

However, what you **should not do**:

- Send the password - because after all, as has already been mentioned, you don't have it.
- Generate a new temporary password - not only is this as insecure as sending the password, it also leads to the possibility of a denial of service attack. I can go to the site, pretend to be you, request a new password and then (if you haven't checked your email) you can't log in, don't know why and have to request a new new password ...

The token is probably the way to go. Receiving it notifies a forgotten password request, but doesn't take any action unless you confirm. You would also make it a one-time token with a relatively short expiry time to limit risk.

Of course, a lot depends on the application. Obviously protecting financial and other sensitive information is more critical than preventing your account being hacked on mytwitteringfacetube.com, because while it's inconvenient, if someone wants to steal someone's identity on a social network site, they can just open their own account and masquerade with stolen information anyway.

Answer (score 10):

Obviously, you can't send the original password by email, because you're not storing it (right?!).  Sending a temporary password (that must be changed, because it only works for one login), and a link to reset the password are equivalent from a security point of view.

Comment: I'm storing the password with AES encryption so I could decrypt it and send it.

Comment: There's really not a good reason to store the passwords in a reversible format, and likely using a symmetric algo like that would add about zero extra security while adding only a false sense of security. Use a proper hash algorithm such as one of the SHA family, or whirlpool, or another modern one, with a salt, and the passwords will be FAR more secure.

Comment: Storing the passwords with encryption is helpful, but not enough - if the attacker has access to your database, there's a good chance he has access to the rest of the system as well (not so for SQL injection, but true for many other types of attacks).  And if your system can decrypt the passwords, so can he.

Comment: Kitsune is correct.  If your database is compromised, it's very likely your AES key will be too.  You should always use one-way cryptographic hashing for passwords.

Comment: Even if the outside attack is very unlikely, there is always a possibility of evil from inside. One of you co-workers might just decrypt the passwords, maybe even sell them. That's why you should only use hashes.

Comment: Please don't send a temporary password right away, only after clicking on a link in the email. Otherwise you can easily reset other peoples password...

Comment: @Pbirkoff, some sites allow two simultaneous passwords (permanent, and temporary emailed one) to get around that.  There's no real difference in security.  Either way, if you see the reset email, you're in.

Answer (score 5):

I don't unnderstand the attitude towards the secret question method. It's not like I am going to make my password "BlueHouse" and then make my security question "What are your two favorite things?" and the answer "Blue and Houses". The security question is not the magic key to get the actual password. It's usually a way to get a new password sent to the email address on file. I don't know how else you guys do it, but it sounds like you do one of two things.

1) The user clicks a "I forgot my password" button and the new password is sent to the user.

2) The user clicks a "I forgot my password" button and then has to answer a security question before getting the new password emailed to the address on file.

Seems to me that option number 2 is more secure.

Why is sending a token any more secure than sending the password? If an email account has been hacked, it's been hacked. It doesn't matter if there is a link to reset the password, a token, or a new password. Don't forget, most sites don't say "The new password has been sent to the following email address for you to hack into". A hacker would need to guess the email address that needs to be hacked.

Comment: "Seems to me that option number 2 is more secure"... yeah, but only trivially, and it irritates users, and they forget the answers.

Comment: The trouble with the secret question method is that the questions are usually things like "mother's maiden name" or "where did you go to school," things that can often be gleaned from a social media profile; if the user is allowed to enter their own secret question, it is usually even weaker. Agree that if the email account has been hacked, all bets are off, although bear in mind that a lot of sites present secret questions as an alternative to using a password reset link, i.e. get the secret question right and you go straight to password reset.

Comment: As far as sending a token vs sending a new password, if you send a new password, whether directly or after a security question is answered, it necessitates that the password is reset, which will lock the user out of their account if they didn't request a new password (and haven't checked their email). It's a DOS attack, where if the hacker can't get into the user's account, then neither can the user. Conversely, a token is merely an authentication to change the password. If the user did not request it, or if they remember their old password, they can ignore it and it will, or should, expire.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Andy.  Aren't security questions normally independent of the password? (mine are)  Meaning they have a question and an answer and aren't related to the password.  It seems like this is used to prevent spurious password reset requests and actually does have a use.

Imagine - someone could go to a site's "forgot password" utility and enter a zillion email addresses - or just one person they want to annoy.  If the password is reset at that point, the people belonging to those email addresses would have to then notice in their email the password reset and login to the site with the reset password next time they went there.  With the security question, this isn't as easy for someone to do.

I see Amazon sends a link to the given email.  They also require you to enter a captcha to prevent DOS attacks.  Because it's a link, I imagine that means they did not reset the password immediately and it would be reset once the user clicks the link.  With the scenario above, the user would just see the email and note that "no I didn't do that" and go about their business not having to change their password needlessly.  A security question might have prevented the attempt at the beginning and the legit user from getting the email in the first place.

Here's a whitepaper on it:
http://appsecnotes.blogspot.com/2010/09/latest-forgot-password-best-practices.html

This one actually recommends secret questions as a major part of the authentication process.  And sending an authentication code via email and requesting it is just an add-on layer you can optionally include.

Comment: Security questions are a weaker form of password. They are also unnecessary because the "forgot password" utility should never reset the password, so all those zillion email addresses will receive a password reset link which they can ignore (or report) but it won't otherwise affect anybody. Yes, it might reduce the number of bogus emails being sent, but it also annoys legitimate users by providing an extra hoop to jump through. And not all sites use email addresses (rightfully so), so having to guess the username is probably more difficult than having to guess the name of their first pet.

Answer (score 4):

It really comes down to how much security you want to have. One the one end of the extreme is a password reset process that involves contacting and certifying that you are who you claim to be, e.g. via id, because your mailbox could be compromised as well. Actually, as people tend to use the same password everywhere this is very likely. On the other end there is the standard approach that involves just sending out an email with a random new password.

"Secret" questions and answers are just another form of username and passwords with the fatal flaw that they are usually incredibly easy to guess, so good that you don't want to use them.

To your point about the token, I don't think it makes a big difference in overall security. Whether you send out a token that allows a user to change the password or whether you send out a random password right away doesn't make a big difference.

Just make sure the token is only usable once and preferably only in a limited time span, e.g. +24h after requesting it.

And, as pointed out by previous answers, NEVER EVER store plain passwords. Hash them. Preferably add [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Comment: The difference between a token and a random password is not much in security necessarily, but it is an opportunity for a denial of service. Don't change a user's password unless they explicitly ask.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I resolved it:

I added `retrieve_token` and `retrieve_expiration` fields to my 'users' table.

The user requests a password reset by providing their email and filling out captcha. A random hashed value is generated for their `retrieve_token` field - i.e. `md5($user_id.time())`, while `retrieve_expiration` will be set to a datetime that expires in next 45 minutes. Email is sent out to the user with a link:

`https://example.com/reset-password?retrieve_token=912ec803b2ce49e4a541068d495ab570`

SSL should be mandatory when authentication is required. You can also add a table for logging reset requests that stores email and the IP address. It helps track down possible brute attacks and you can block attacker's IP if necessary.

You could implement security question for requesting password reset, but I feel captcha would be enough to discourage anyone from repeating the request multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

@Jay. The reason why you go to a URL to reset your password instead of just sending someone a new temporary password is more than just security. Without something like a URL with a token, a person could reset another persons password. There is no need to gain access to the email. If someone had a bone to pick with someone, they could just keep initiating a new password reset. Then the poor target has to logon and change the password again and again.

By sending a token, the user's password does not change until they login with it and confirm it. The spam of reset emails can be ignored. Tokens are just as easy (if not easier) to generate as a new password by using a GUID, it's not really extra hassle for the developer.

Also, because the GUID is unique (a generated password might not be), a token can be tied to a username. If the incorrect username is given on the URL, then the token can be cancelled (i.e. when a different person initiates it and someone intercepts it.. assuming that the username isn't the same as the email).

Answer (score 1):

@Jay. The proper use of security questions is to initiate a password reset email, not for actually resetting the password. Without a mechanism such as a security question, one could initiate a password reset. Althought seemingly beign, sending a reset email could be sent to an email that might no longer belong to the original owner. This is not rare. For example, when employees leave a company, often those mails are forwarded to another employee. A security question, adds a low level of obfucation to that scenario. It also reduces issues where one person keeps initiating a password reset on the wrong account causing some poor sod to get unintentionally spammed. Security question are really not meant to be truely secure, they are just meant to reduce scenarios such as those. Anyone using a security question to actually reset the password is doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding security question/answer. As a user of websites I personally don't use them (I enter garbage in them). But they are certainly not useless or meaningless as some say here.

Consider this situation: 
A user of your site has left his desk to go to lunch and didn't lock his workstation. A nefarious user can now visit the page for recovering/resetting password and enter the user's username. The system will then email the recovered/reset password without prompting for the security answer.

Comment: but why assume the the nefarious person doesn't have access to the security questions? Anything I will be able to remember myself, e.g. mother's maiden name, birthtown, first pet, etc. is NOT secret information. I might blog, tweet, or mention it in casual conversation. Thus, people around my desk who are most likely to have access to my computer will also know my 'secret' security answers. It's certainly easily open to social engineering.

Comment: @yochannah, I agree that it does not provide a strong protection, but, as I said, it is not useless. A problem might be that it gives the user a false feeling of good security, but I would not say that this motivates us to not include this feature at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how someone did it with Node.js, basically generate a random token, an expiry time, send out the link with the token attached, have a `reset/:token` route that ensures a user exists with that token (which is also not expired) and, if so, redirect to a reset password page.

http://sahatyalkabov.com/how-to-implement-password-reset-in-nodejs/