# Send Forget Password using E Mail in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, email

i am using a **asp.net framework** for sending a **forget password** through **E-Mail**.
but i think there's some problem in my code.
please help .
The **button_click** event code is give below.

```
        protected void frgtbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
             string st = "select E_mail FROM registraion_master WHERE E_mail='" +     Email.Text + "'";

           cmd = new SqlCommand(st, sqlcon);
           cmd.Connection.Open();
           SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           DataSet ds=new DataSet();
           sda.Fill(ds);
           cmd.Connection.Close();
           if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
              {
                 MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
                 email.From = new MailAddress(Email.Text); //Enter sender email address.
                 email.To.Add(Email.Text); //Destination Recipient e-mail address.
                 email.Subject = "Your Forget Password:"; //Subject for your request.
                 email.Body = "Hi,Your Password is: " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Pwd"] + "";

                 email.IsBodyHtml = true;
                 //SMTP SERVER DETAILS
                 SmtpClient smtpc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                 smtpc.Port = 587;
                 smtpc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                 smtpc.EnableSsl = true;
                 gmail_ID.Text = "anuragdixit132@gmail.com";//Enter your gmail id here
                 gmail_pwd.Text="vineet";//Enter your gmail id here
                 smtpc.Credentials = new   NetworkCredential(gmail_ID.Text,gmail_pwd.Text);
                 smtpc.Send(email);
                 string script = @"<script language=""javascript""> alert('Password Has Been Sent.......!!!!!.');
                 </script>;";
                 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myJScript1", script);
                }
              else
                {
                pwdlbl.Text = "This email address is not exist in our Database try again";
                }
```

in this code : there is an exception occour:**Column 'Pwd' does not belong to table Table.**

Comment: I suspect you storing your passwords as a plain text. **Don't do that!** Please read: [Implement password recovery best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734367/implement-password-recovery-best-practice) You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Is that not fairly obvious that **Column 'Pwd' is not in the table**, also as @SonerGönül said, **Don't store passwords like that**

Comment: oh and the reason 'Pwd' isn't in the table is likely because you only get the column `E_mail` in your select statement, and then don't use it, as well as using a non-parameterised query with text entry in the select clause...

Comment: In addition to not storing passwords as plain text, you should also use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead of using string concatenation to build your sql string (`WHERE E_mail='" +     Email.Text + "'`)

Comment: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
This Error occures...
@JamesBarrass this is my own project actually.

Comment: @AnuragDixit Where it states **Column 'Pwd' does not belong to table Table** it means in the data set which is the result of your select statement `SELECT E_mail FROM`. You only select E_mail so only E_mail exists in the result set. It doesn't matter too much if it's your own project but I would still recommend good practices.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9572958/1048425) for more information on the authentication error.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way to reproduce your problem:

```
   string st = "select E_mail FROM registraion_master WHERE E_mail='" +     Email.Text + "'";
   cmd = new SqlCommand(st, sqlcon);
   cmd.Connection.Open();
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataSet ds=new DataSet();
   sda.Fill(ds);
   cmd.Connection.Close();
   ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Pwd"];
```

It is clear that you are quering the db only for E_mail and not Pwd. If the Pwd is part of the registraion_master table than the solution can be:

```
  string st = "select E_mail,Pwd FROM registraion_master WHERE E_mail='" +     Email.Text + "'";
```

However I hope the pwd is not saved in plaintext. And start using parameterized queries, your query is subject to sql injection. And I guess that you also have cross site scripting problems when displaying user input on your screens, you have that cross site scripting when you are sending the password to a user...

Comment: I hope I'm not an user on your site... Fix your sql injection and cross site scripting. Best is to send a new password to your users when they have lost the old one.