# While reset password when after clicking to link from email going to resetPassword jsp page after enter password it's taking whole path

Tags: java, spring-mvc

<-----Controller----->

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/verifyEmail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String verifyEmail(@ModelAttribute("signup") Signup signup, ModelMap map,HttpSession session) {
    String emailData = null;
    try {
        list = forgotPasswordService.verifyEmail(signup.getEmail());

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        map.addAttribute("worning", "Invalid Email try again..");
        return "forgotPassword";

    } else {
        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            emailData = (String) iterator.next();

        }

    }
    if (emailData.equals(signup.getEmail())) {

        mailUtil.sendMail(signup.getEmail());
        session.setAttribute("email1",signup.getEmail());
        return "checkMail";

    } else {
        System.out.println("---------------");
        return "forgotPassword";
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/resetPassword/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String resetPassword(@PathVariable String email,Map<String, String> map) {

    System.out.println("Email: "+email);
    map.put("emailId", email);


    return "resetPassword";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/passwordChanged", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setNewPassword(@ModelAttribute("Signup") Signup signUp, ModelMap map) {

    forgotPasswordService.setNewPassword(signUp.getEmail(), signUp.getPassword());
    map.addAttribute("msg", "Password changed Successfully..");
    return "SignupReg";
}
```

<-----JSP--->

```
<form action="passwordChanged" method="get">
    <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="email" value="${email}" readonly ></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
         <!-- <tr>
            <td>Conform-Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password1"></td>
        </tr> -->
        <tr> 

            <td><center>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
                </center></td>

        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

<--- browser   -->

url:
http://localhost:2525/VendorApp/resetPassword/'deepaksahu@gmail.com/passwordChanged?email=%27deepaksahu9119%40gmail.com&password=sahu

error:404
 The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Is it just me or someone could just 1. call /passwordChanged directly and 2. profits? May be worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734367/implement-password-recovery-best-practice

Comment: Please divide to short and having meaning subject, details in body. Use dot and commas, many people can't read long chaotic sentences

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the form-method in the first Html/JSP line to `"post"`. It should look like this:

```
<form action="passwordChanged" method="post">
```

You also have to change the line

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resetPassword/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resetPassword/{email}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: thankyou for valueable suggestion, but that was not a problem.I have fixed the problem.