# Forgotten password in webapp

Tags: php, passwords, password-recovery

I'm currently working on the administration pages for my website, and I've now reached a point where I'm starting to look at how a user can retrieve or be given a password if they forget the original.

I've not had to deal with anything like this before and I'm not sure which solution to use as there seems to be a number of ways to deal with this. So I thought I'd ask the more seasoned developers. What is the best method to deal with a 'Password Retrieval'

If it helps, when the user initially registers they have to provide an email address and password, which is then encrypted using salt.

Comment: DO NOT offer a way to send the user's password to them. ANY implementation of said feature is NOT secure. This means the method your using to protect their password is useless. THE ONLY method you should allow them to use, is to reset their password, after they have provided some other bit of information they supplied.  Unless your using an encryption algorithm, what you want is not even possible, since a hasing algorithm cannot be reversed.  If you are using an encryption algorithm.

Comment: There's a good answer to this here [Effective Techniques for Password Retrieval in Modern Web Applications][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910856/effective-techniques-for-password-retrieval-in-modern-web-applications

Comment: @IRHM : +1, for a nice question, helped me too, to learn something new. Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prefer to get the user to enter their email address and then:

a. Create a hash when the user submits the request and store it (which should expire after a certain amount of time - BloodyWorld).

b. The user is sent a link with that hash in.

c. They click the link which should go to a secure page on your site, you verify its valid making sure the hash you saved matches the one in the link then ask them to re-generate a password.

Comment: I recommence to give that hash an expiration date, e.g. 1h from request.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply I certainly like this idea. I don't suppose you know of any tutorials that I could work from please?

Comment: @IRHM - I've not used a tutorial on this so couldn't recommend one. However, if you break down my thoughts into steps you should be able to Google some tutorials for each part.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are hashing the password it can't be retrieved.  You will have to create a temporary password and send it to the user.  Have them then log in with the temporary password and then create a new one.

Comment: And you should be hashing rather than encrypting the password after salting it...

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to reply. Sorry my mistake, incorrect terminology. I am hashing the password. Kind regards