# Password recovery when using password_hash function

Tags: php, mysql, forgot-password, password-recovery, password-hash

I am currently using `password_hash` which is one-way hash function so cannot be decrypted. So what exactly should I do for providing password recovery feature for users in case they forget password. Is there any built-in function like `verify_password`.

Comment: No one should ever be able to recover an old password - only create a new one :-)

Comment: Also, what exactly do you imagine the "*`verify password`*" function should do?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest one is, you can email a link to reset the old password with the new one to the user who have forgotten his/her password. This doesn't require decrypting the old password and is pretty secure.

And also, I think this question might be helpful 
[Effective Techniques for Password Retrieval in Modern Web Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910856/effective-techniques-for-password-retrieval-in-modern-web-applications)