# Spring MVC BCryptPasswordEncoder issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encryption

I have this catch 22 situation in my project which i dont really know how to solve. This application is created on Spring MVC, where as an Admin, i can Create/Update users . Now i am using BCryptPasswordEncoder to encrypt the password of the created user which is stored in an MySql DB.

Now the problem is due to the fact we can't really decode the encrypted password encrypted with  BCryptPasswordEncoder . For ex. now i created a user with a password say **"SpringMVC@#"** after clicking save it gets encrypted by the encoder it becomes something like **"$2a$10$Cjcstw1UKZstCA19NiF4mOGMHMEMFojNozW5fH7qZ5RJ7Atz24IzG"** which is 
a 60 char long salted value. Now there is no way i can decrypt this value and have that displayd as *************** (equivalent of  **SpringMVC@#** ) in the password field on the Update user screen which is causing a major problem.

While creating the user I enter these fields : **UserName , Password, Role, Active Indicator** (which is dropdown list with values Y or N)

[image]

Now the issue is when i go to the update screen to update the user details, the password value is fetched from the DB and shown as below :

[image]

The Password shown here is actually the encrypted / salted one which is 60 characters long which is fetched from the  DB. Now the problem is when I update one field (say Role) and click on **Submit** it also updates the password (which is already encrypted) with double encryption i.e. the value is again salted and updated. And There is no way i can know what value gets stored in the DB after the update. So when this user tries to log in to the application again it fails stating that its bad credentials.

Here is the code to my **SecurityConfig.java** file which extends **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```
 @Autowired
  DBAuthenticationService DBAauthenticationService;

 @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     auth.userDetailsService(dbAauthenticationService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

  }
  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
  }
```

Here is the snippet of code from the UserController.java :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView saveUsersData(@ModelAttribute @Valid USerModel model, BindingResult result) {
    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
      try {
        String roleUser = model.getUserRole();
        model.setPassWord(pwEncode.encode(model.getPassWord()));
        userDao.saveUsersData(model, getUserId(), roleUser);
        userDao.setIsNewRecord(false);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/userListPage");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        //print 
      }
    }
    return new ModelAndView("addUser");
  }
```

Now , my queries are :

1) Is there anyway i can decode the encrypted DB password? 
OR 
2) Is there another way I can get around this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot decode it as it will do hashing not encrypting..

Comment: It is not advisable to store the users password in a way that you could decrypt it. One should only be storing the hash or the encrypted hash. A good solution is to provide a way for the user to reset their password (e.g. via email link). Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910856/effective-techniques-for-password-retrieval-in-modern-web-applications

Comment: @GeorgeAndrews  thanks for your reply., the issue here the design of the application. Its only the admin that can update user details including the Password and then inform the user. So this option is not going to work in this case.

Comment: @Joe In practice, an admin should not be able to view a user's password. A reset process is still a better practice.

Comment: That said, I understand I did not specifically answer your question. To answer the question: 1) No, you cannot decode the bcrypt hashed password. 2) One alternative would be to provide a different way to reset passwords (e.g. a reset link via email). It would not be advisable to store a password in a way that an admin is able to decode or view the actual password. Sorry I could not be of more help!